# Redundant code in exception handling

Tags: c++

I've a recurrent problem, I don't find an elegant solution to avoid the resource cleaning code duplication:

```
resource allocation:

try {
  f()
} catch (...) {
  resource cleaning code;
  throw;
}

resource cleaning code;
return rc;
```

So, I know I can do a temporary class with cleaning up destructor, but I don't really like it because it breaks the code flow and I need to give the class the reference to the all stack vars to cleanup, the same problem with a function, and I don't figure out how does not exists an elegant solution to this recurring problem.

Comment: The elegant solution *IS* creating classes with deallocation handled in their destructors: this is called RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)

Comment: I expect C++1x' lambdas to do wonders to RAII.

Comment: @sbi: does RAII need wonders done to it?

Comment: @John: Yes, definitely. I mean, this is what that famous article of Alexandrescu and Marginean has been all about: making ad-hoc use of RAII easier. Yes, it's better to have nice, cleanly designed classes manage resources, but sometimes you just have to have some ad-hoc resource management. For this, imagine a universal RAII class, which takes an `std::function` in its ctor, and invokes it in its dtor, initialized with a lambda function object.

Comment: Doesn't C++ have try {} catch {} **finally** {} then?

Comment: @JeremyP: Standard C++ doesn't have `finally`.

Comment: @Jeremy No, it doesn't need one - RAII is far superior.

Comment: @Nicola If you find yourself writing many try/catch blocks, you are not using C++ properly.

Comment: @sbi:  I want to read the article you refer to if I haven't already.  Is this it?  http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758;jsessionid=XAFGRJ33LCON5QE1GHOSKHWATMY32JVN

Comment: @John: Yes, that one. (At the time I wrote this, Jackson had just referred to it in his answer, so I considered it obvious. Sorry.)

Comment: @sbi that's what I get for not following links!

Comment: @Neil:  I would think there is room for both.  RAII is great if you have control over the implementation of the classes you want to use but if a class you want to use requires explicit deallocation of some resource, with RAII you'd need to wrap it in something that implements the RAII part.

Comment: @JaremyP Yaaa! Sure, java finally block would fit my needs...
@Neil I'm used to RAII, but really not always fits the needs. For example I've to stop an alarm during execution and restart at the end. Too code to write for just an alarm restore, and it breaks code readability. Cam'on, has no sense the class AlarmRestoreHelper, too specific... And lambda+boost are still too... brrr. Finally is the only thing I miss from java, simple and elegant.

Comment: @Neil 300 times in a project of 400k lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at boost::scope_exit:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 8):

This problem is why RAII was invented. The best practice is to make sure that **every** releasable resource is inside an object. Alternately, you can use Boost.ScopeExit or define a generic sentinel class (a class that receives a functor in constructor and calls it in the destructor)

**Edit**: In the article pointed out by @Jackson, this is called `ScopeGuard`. The implementation in the article could greatly enhanced by combining it with `boost::function` and `boost::bind` - or `std::tr1::function` and `std::tr1::bind`).

Basically instead of the whole architecture in the article, your implementation would look like this:

```
class scoped_guard
{
    boost::function<void(void)> atScopeExit;
public:
    scoped_guard(const boost::function<void(void)>& func) : atScopeExit(func) {}
    ~scoped_guard() { try { atScopeExit(); } catch(...) {} }
};
```

You can further enhance this by adding the capability to dismiss it or other things (capturing exceptions safely in case of stack unwinding?) but 
<strike>I'm too lazy to</strike> that's left as an exercise to the reader ;).

Comment: Ya, I know, but scope_guard+boost+lambda are still too unreadable, error generators and complicate solutions for the problem. Somebody should propose this syntax for the c++3x ;)

  try {
    code;
  }
  anyway {
    cleanup;
  }
  catch (...) {
    throw;
  }

Comment: @Nicola, they are not so unreadable - they're just a code construct you have to be familiar with (especially since it looks like it's here to stay - so you'll probably see it more and more in code).

Answer (score 2):

This [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758) article might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need self-releasing resources, which is really not hard to do.

For memory use autopointers, STL, Boost or make your own, it isn't hard.

For files, preferably use an std::fstream.  If you must use fopen or CreateFile (or whatever) make a simple handle class that calls the appropriate close function on destruction.

Similarly for any other resources, build a collection of smart handle classes.